# How to send a file to the recycle bin / trash in OSX (or Windows) with R?

Tags: r, windows, macos

Everything is in the title.

`file.remove("test.txt")` deletes the file completely, I would like to send it to trash as if I used the UI of the OS (like Finder in OSX). Is it possible in R?

Comment: Copy it to the "trash" folder before you delete it.

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I feel dumb. Thank you though :-).